# how to process last x lines of a file

Tags: shell, ksh

I want to Analyse a logfile for specific Errors. 
Therefore i want to be able to loop through the last x lines of the files and check every line with a specific REGEX Pattern and then define a specific return value.

The logfile Looks in case of success as follows at the Moment when i want to check it.
    
    `….
    sftp> get blahblah/blahblah
    sftp> bye`

In case of an Error there is something between the two sftp lines.

What i allready tried is to solve the Problem with a specific regex which worked fine on some online Regex testers but couldn´t get it to work in ksh.

My current Approach is the following

```
LOG_FIL="test_log"
MODE="${1}"

check_log_file() {
  ERRNBR=${1}
  REGEX=${2}
  TAIL=${3}
  RETURN="0"
  echo "ERRNBR = ${ERRNBR}"
  echo "REGEX = ${REGEX}"
  echo "TAIL = ${TAIL}"

  while read line; do
     echo "${line}"
     if [[ "${line}" =~ ${REGEX} ]]; then
        RETURN="0"
        echo "bin hier"
     else
        RETURN=${ERRNBR}
        echo "bin wo anders"
        break
     fi
  done <<<$(tail -${TAIL} ${LOG_FIL})
  echo "${RETURN}"
  return ${RETURN}
}

echo "sftp> get cwi/cdk_final*" >> ${LOG_FIL}

if [ "${MODE}" == "1" ]; then 
  echo "Werner ist der beste" >>${LOG_FIL}
fi

check_log_file "22" "^(sftp> ).*$" "1"
echo "$?"

echo "sftp> bye" >> ${LOG_FIL}

check_log_file "21" "((sftp> ).*|(sftp> bye))" "2"
echo "$?"
```

The results i get are the following

```
edv> sh cdk_test4sftp.sh 1
ERRNBR = 22
REGEX = ^(sftp> ).*$
TAIL = 1
Werner ist der beste
bin wo anders
22
22
ERRNBR = 21
REGEX = ((sftp> ).*|(sftp> bye))
TAIL = 2
Werner ist der beste sftp> bye
bin hier
0
0
```

What i hoped to achieve was that the Output coming from the tail command would be seperated. So that i ccould test each line individually.

Comment: I think `<<<` at the end of your loop may be the problem, maybe try `tail -N logfile | while read .... done` Also, put a shebang as the first line of your script to ensure you are using the shell you are targeting.

Comment: Shorten it just to `tail -${TAIL} ${LOG_FIL} | grep "${REGEX}"`. Like `if tail -${TAIL} ${LOG_FIL} | grep -q "${REGEX}"; then something; else ; something; fi;` Using `while read` with `[[ =~` will be very slow. `grep` will be magnitudes faster and more portable.

Comment: Thank you for the Feedback.@Mark that was my first Approach and iterating over the lines was no Problem but it is not posible with this Approach to save Output into a global variable was not possible because the piped while loop is executed in a subshell and so the value of variables inside the loop will be discarded. @Kamil I tried this Approach, or better said it was my fist attempt. but grep is not able to process multiline REGEX paterns.

Comment: `multiline REGEX` - but with `while read` you are reading one line at a time anyway. And without `IFS=` you are removing leading and trailing whitespaces and without `-r` backslashes are wrongly interpreted. Read [How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).  Just use `grep -z` then.

Comment: Did you try `tail -${TAIL} ${LOG_FIL} | grep "${REGEX}"` as @KamilCuk suggested? Or `tail ... | grep -v 'sftp>'` ?

Answer (score 0):

Your second regex:

```
((sftp> ).*|(sftp> bye))
```

Matches the following line, which is why your function returns 0:

Werner ist der beste **sftp> bye**

Since you want to match the following pattern on each line:

```
sftp> get blahblah/blahblah
sftp> bye
```

Your regex should look more like the first one you used to match:

```
^(sftp> ).*$
```